# How can I get an album URL from the Picasa API?

Tags: python, picasa

I really don't like the Picasa feed-oriented API. Why couldn't they create a REST interface?

Does anyone know how I can get the URL for a particular album? For example, say I have:

```
gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()
albums = gd_client.GetUserFeed(user="user@gmail.com")
album = albums.entry[0]
```

How can I find its URL? I am looking for something like:

```
http://picasaweb.google.com/username/AlbumTitle
```

so that when I click on it, it will take me to Picasa to view that album!

PS: Note that you cannot just put the `album.title` there because it might contain spaces, and it's not really the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can access an album's picasaweb url through calling `.GetHtmlLink().href` on an entry

```
album_urls = [album.GetHtmlLink().href for album in albums.entry]
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the album URL by going to `http://picasaweb.google.com/[username]/[album title]`.

Comment: That's not really what he was asking for.